# Why use index method instead of special method in Lua

Tags: c, lua

```
lua_State*  m_state;
luaL_newmetatable(m_state,LUA_DATACLIENT);

lua_pushcfunction(m_state,DataClient_Index);
lua_setfield(m_state,-2,"__index");

lua_pushcfunction(m_state,DataClient_newIndex);
lua_setfield(m_state,-2,"__newindex");

lua_pushcfunction(m_state,DataClient_RequestData);
lua_setfield(m_state,-2,"RequestData");

lua_pushcfunction(m_state,DataClient_free);
lua_setfield(m_state,-2,"__gc");
lua_pop(m_state,1);
```

I want to export some C function to Lua, but the function `DataClient_Index` was called when I call `RequestData` in Lua, so why use index method instead of special method in Lua?

Comment: I call lua function in follow code    `dataclient:RequestData()` ,I am sure it has no spelling error.

Comment: lua version is 5.2 @prapin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua does not look **by default** in the metatable when performing an indexing operation.

- for *tables*, `__index` metamethod is only triggered when the index does not exist in the table.
- for *userdata*, `__index` is *always* called since there is no possibility to store key-values inside the userdata.

For *userdata objects*, it is customary to place *methods* inside the metatable. For that to work however, the `__index` metatable field shall either be the metatable itself, or a function that tries to find the index inside the metatable.

If you choose the first solution (this simplest), you can write something like:

```
lua_State*  m_state;
luaL_newmetatable(m_state,LUA_DATACLIENT);

lua_pushvalue(m_state, -1); // push the metatable
lua_setfield(m_state,-2,"__index"); // __index points to the metatable itself

// ...
```

Comment: Is there has any more choose?